# Automatic conversion of stucture to pointer in function call

Tags: pointers, structure, visual-studio-2003, abi

We have a pretty normal looking `printf` style function in our project, with the modification that the `%g` format means to print a GUID instead of the normal floating-point type.  For our case, a GUID looks something like this:

```
struct guid {
  uint32_t  Data1;
  uint16_t  Data2;
  uint16_t  Data3;
  uint8_t   Data4[8];
};
```

In reality, the print function expects a pointer to the GUID to be passed, as opposed to the structure itself:

```
struct guid myGuid = { 0x867FD1E7, 0x9AA7, 0x472A, { 0xAA, 0x56, 0xF2, 0xDA, 0x66, 0x62, 0xCD, 0x4D } };
print("%g", &myGuid);
```

There are several places in the source base, however, where for some reason the entire guid is passed:

```
print("%g", myGuid);
```

This style of call seems to work fine with MSVC2003 - is there some ABI requirement that makes the compiler translate that function call style to actually pass a pointer behind the scenes?  When porting this codebase to use clang/llvm, it certainly doesn't do the same thing.

Can somebody explain why the second version of the call works with MSVC?  A pointer to the appropriate documentation would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found some clarification on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> Any argument that doesn’t fit in 8 bytes, or is not 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes, must be passed by reference.

Looks like it's time to fix clang!